# Caption don't follow tikzpicture scaleing causeing weird whitespace

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

When adding my fill between lines it caused the scaling to stop working my nodes were easy to fix but the caption now has a weird distance between the figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
%\usepackage[margin=0.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\small} %ta bort om inte behöver platsen
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
% We will externalize the figures
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
                xlabel={$q$},
                 ylabel={$p$},
                 xlabel style={below right},
                 ylabel style={above right},
                 ymin=0,
                 xmin=0,
                 xmax=1.05,
                 ymax=1.05,
                 yticklabels={,,},
                 xticklabels={,,}]
        \addplot[name path=D,color=red,   domain = 0:1]{-3*x+1.5}
        node [color=black, pos=0.2, above right,scale=0.7] {Efterfrågan};
        \addplot[name path=SuS,color=blue,  samples = 100, domain = 0:1]{4*(x-0.1)^2+0.15}
        node [ color=black, pos=0.3,below right,scale=0.7] {Skattfritt utbud};
          \addplot[name path =SS,color=magenta,  samples = 100, domain = 0:1]{((4*(x-0.1)^2+0.15)+0.03)*1.4}
        node [color=black, pos=0.07,above left,align=center,scale=0.7] {Utbud\\med skatt};
    \addplot[color=blue,fill opacity=0.3] fill between[of=SuS and SS];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Utbuds påverkan av skatt}
    \label{fig:Skatt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by moving that scaling into the axis conditions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
                xlabel={$q$},
                 ylabel={$p$},
                 xlabel style={below right},
                 ylabel style={above right},
                 ymin=0,
                 xmin=0,
                 xmax=1.05,
                 ymax=1.05,
                 yticklabels={,,},
                 xticklabels={,,}]
        \addplot[name path=D,color=red,   domain = 0:1]{-3*x+1.5}
        node [color=black, pos=0.2, above right,scale=0.7] {Efterfrågan};
        \addplot[name path=SuS,color=blue,  samples = 100, domain = 0:1]{4*(x-0.1)^2+0.15}
        node [ color=black, pos=0.3,below right,scale=0.7] {Skattfritt utbud};
          \addplot[name path =SS,color=magenta,  samples = 100, domain = 0:1]{((4*(x-0.1)^2+0.15)+0.03)*1.4}
        node [color=black, pos=0.07,above left,align=center,scale=0.7] {Utbud\\med skatt};
    \addplot[color=blue,fill opacity=0.3] fill between[of=SuS and SS];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an mwe for an complete answer ...